# Deep link without updating apple store

Tags: ios, deep-linking, deeplink

I like implement deep link in my app, without update the app.

Is it possible to implement deep link in my app without updating my app store?

Comment: how did you implemente deep linking ?

Comment: *HOW* should the device know of any deep linking change without you updating the app?

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you already have code in your app to handle the deeplinking and just do not have in the push notification.

You need code in your app to handle the deeplink from the push notification and open the correct viewcontroller.